# Why Installing OpenCV is so difficult?

Tags: python, opencv, installation, anaconda

When I try to install OpenCV with Python on OSX I get errors. Even with Anaconda, the situation is the same. Is there any standard installation way to install OpenCV with Python on Mac?

I will go step by step :

1. My system Configuration :

Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.6

2. I tried [Pyimagesearch installation guide](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/), In the step 8 I had an error related to QT error. So I read many articles and tried but none of them could help.
3. I then used [Anaconda Opencv installation guide](https://gist.github.com/welch/6468594) and tried to install again but again got stuck at step 4,  It prints the below error :

   ```
    fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
    #include <Python.h>
             ^ 1 error generated. make[2]: *** 
    [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] 
     Error 1 make[1]: *** 
    [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2 make: 
     *** [all] Error 2
   ```

I have been trying almost spent a day just in installing OpenCV with anaconda, brew and other stuffs. Does any one know a standard way to install OpenCV with Python on anaconda? Or do you know how to solve the aforementioned error?

Comment: did you try this command `conda install -c menpo opencv` in the conda command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but when try to check it by `import cv2`, it gave me an error ` import cv2
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/thiyaga/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/thiyaga/anaconda/lib/libopencv_hdf.3.2.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: how about this link: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv

Comment: the python error is due to anaconda putting the libs in other places. See this bug [report](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/843). Did you follow the second guide step by step, specially step 3 where you say where the python lib is? (this line is not just copy paste, you have to change something) also, check if the folder exists

Comment: @api55 Below is my cmake I used, and its similar to the link that you referred `cmake -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/thiyaga/anaconda/include/python3.6m/ -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/Users/thiyaga/anaconda/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/thiyaga/anaconda/bin/python -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/Users/thiyaga/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ ..`

Comment: @JeruLuke, It gives the same error as mentioned above

Comment: If you copy paste your cmake command, then it is wrong... it is `-DVAR=VAL` no spaces after the `-D`

Comment: BTW, you can try to use `ccmake` or something similar (not if it is available for your system, in linux is the package `cmake-curses-gui`), to see what is set up in the cmake variables

Comment: @api55, really? but anyways both with space or without space, the results are same.

Comment: `brew install opencv3 --with-python3 --with-qt` is the easiest.